# Angular Infdig Error, but function is running properly

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I am continuously getting 'Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop' on my app, but the actual function that is causing it is still displaying properly in the browser.

Inside my controller, I am creating the following function:

```
$scope.time = function(id){
   return new Date(parseInt(id.substring(0, 8), 16) * 1000);
}
```

In my HTML, I am trying to show the time that a blog post was created by pulling in the post's mongoDB id, which I convert to the appropriate format in the $scope.time function:

```
<span am-time-ago="time(post._id)"></span>
```

From console.logs and testing in the controller, I can see that:

1. The correct id is being pulled in from Mongo
2. The $scope.time() function is correctly converting the id into a date string
3. The date string is showing up the way I want in the browser

So, what is causing the infinite loop and how can I remove it while still showing the data in this same format?

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm basing this answer on the assumption that you are using angular-moment.

It looks like angular-moment `'am-time-ago'` directive is expecting a model value so it will keep invoking your `time` function resulting in infinite digest cycles.

So rather construct the time when you get your model and pass this value to the `'am-time-ago'` directive. Something like this:

```
$scope.post.$time = $scope.time($scope.post._id);
```

and your markup would be

```
<span am-time-ago="post.$time"></span>
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MqQh2wqHoyUCEDjq9bmz?p=preview). Open the console to view when the error occurs.